# Load Dojo Packages Dynamically

Tags: javascript, dynamic, dojo, package, esri

I am setting up a mapping application and can't figure out part of the workflow.  I am using ESRI's JS API, which uses a Dojo back.  I am pulling data in from a database and loading it into a hidden field to be parsed on load.

My problem comes when I want to set which packages Dojo loads.  I have the package name and package URL, and I am trying to get them to dynamically load.  But I also need to be able to use those packages to create new objects, like map layer objects.

I have an initial `require` statement that loads the map itself:

```
require(["application/bootstrapmap", "dojo/domReady!"],
            function (BootstrapMap) {
                // Get a reference to the ArcGIS Map class
                map = BootstrapMap.create("map", {
                    basemap: "national-geographic",
                    center: [-122.45, 37.77],
                    zoom: 12,
                    scrollWheelZoom: true,
                });
            });
```

Then I want to be able to dynamically load different packages based off a configuration database table.  I thought I might be able to do something like:

```
$.each(packages, function (index, iPackage) {
        var packageURL = iPackage["PackageURL"];
        var packageName = iPackage["PackageName"];
        dojo.config.packages.push({ location: packageURL, name: packageName });
    });
```

Or my other attempt was:

```
$.each(packages, function (index, iPackage) {
        var packageURL = iPackage["PackageURL"];
        var packageName = iPackage["PackageName"];
        require([locationURL], function(packageName){});
    });
```

I am basically trying to find a way to first load a map object, then parse through the JSON I inserted into the page to add layers dynamically.  I would like to only load what I need instead of loading all the various modules and just picking and choosing which ones to use later.  I would rather load and use right away.

I am looking for any advice to get a set up like this working.

Comment: You say loading packages dynamically, but do you really mean modules?  Packages are normally defined up-front, but defining packages doesn't load anything.  Modules are loaded when you pass specific module IDs to `require` or `define`, and loading modules dynamically should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Ok.  Modules then, I supposed my terminology is a bit messed up.  My biggest thing is when I go to load in modules, I am looking to reference them and use them.  I am curious how it works when I am trying to do this in a loop like the sample code?  Within a `require` or `define` statement, how would I reference it.  Use `packageName` or the variable contents, e.g. `ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer`?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, even though you can probably achieve what you are after, I wouldn't recommend this. It is a wrong design to me, as once you already know which modules are going to need, why do you need to parameterize it ?

Secondly, and that's just FYI, make sure you have the dojoConfig with the packages urls setup prior loading the dojo.js itself (or prior referencing the esri library which is pretty much a dojo package). You cannot set nor modify any other properties to the config object after it's been referenced.

let's say this should be loaded at the time your page is being loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    var dojoConfig = {  
                        async: true,
                        cacheBust: false,
                        locale: 'en-au',
                        paths: {
                            "customModulePath": "/modules/custom",
                        }
                    };
</script>
```

then, whenever you are ready to use anything dojo/esri related call or inject the script (even though loading it as one of the first scripts in the page wouldn't hurt)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jsapi/3.13/jsapicompact/init.js"></script>
```

and then (maked sure it's loaded!)

```
var parameters = [ {
        url: "customModulePath/A",
        name: "ParameterA"
    },{
        url: "customModulePath/B",
        name: "ParameterB"
    };

var urls = [];
for (var p in parameters){
    urls.push(parameters[p].url);
}

require(urls, function(){
    for (var p in parameters){
        // use the function arguments to map it back!
        this[parameters[p].name] = arguments[p];
    }

    // Now access your arguments like
    console.log(this.ParameterA);
    console.log(this.ParameterB);

    // It is advisable to check if it is an object or a function before you use it.
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I don't exactly think it is possible to do what I want, but I wanted to ask people who knew more.  I think I can do it, but I would need to do more manual parsing of the info then `require` the module and use it.  Basically, add more `if then` code in there for configuration purposes.